# How to customize TabbedPage tabbar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The page displays the schedule. Tabs are Monday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday. I want to make a back button to the left of Monday, similarly at the end of the week. This will allow navigation between weeks.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjVRi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You might try using < and > as the first and last tab?  You will probably have to create a custom tab bar and not use the builtin one.

Answer (score 0):

According to uploaded picture, it seems that it can be implemented by **TabControl**, but I recommend you use **ScrollView** to implement it. And the back button can be implemented very well, you only need to scroll the view to switch between months. The specific implementation ideas are as follows:

1, **Scroll view**: FlowCalendarView, responsible for achieving unlimited scrolling, loading the required month view;

2, **Month view**: MonthView, responsible for generating the corresponding day view according to the date, and layout the sky view and the auxiliary view;

3, **Day view**: DayView, responsible for generating the corresponding click event, ui display, etc.;

In this way, the above day of the week only needs to be displayed with the label, and the back button can be put on the button with the back icon, and they can be placed in the layout and placed on the scrollview. The advantage of **Scrollview** is that the refresh of the interface is better than the **TabControl**.